# Configure Jenkin's SonarQube section using Job-DSL

Tags: groovy, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-job-dsl

Using Job-DSL we can configure a C# project in Jenkins.

The SonarQube tasks is giving us a hard time.

```
        StepContext.metaClass.sonar = {
        -> NodeBuilder nodeBuilder = new NodeBuilder()
            stepNodes << nodeBuilder.'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder' {
                jdk('(Inherit From Job)')
                usePrivateRepository(false)
            }
    }
```

How to set the path to the `sonar-project.properties` config file, using the Job-DSL script?

[image: Sonar section]

**Final script**

Thanks to @Bruno César, I added `pathToSonarProjectProperties` as parameter.

```
    StepContext.metaClass.sonar = { String pathToSonarProjectProperties
        -> NodeBuilder nodeBuilder = new NodeBuilder()
            stepNodes << nodeBuilder.'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder' {
                jdk('(Inherit From Job)')
                usePrivateRepository(false)
                project(pathToSonarProjectProperties)
            }
    }
```

The `sonar` function is called with the relative-to-project-root path of `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar("Framework\\xxx\\xxx\\sonar-project.properties")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [`SonarRunnerBuilder`](https://github.com/SonarSource/jenkins-sonar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarRunnerBuilder.java) class there is a `project` attribute that represents the path to a file with properties for the project.

In the same way in which you set the JDK (`jdk('(Inherit From Job)')`) you can set the path property. In your example, try like this:

```
StepContext.metaClass.sonar = {
    -> NodeBuilder nodeBuilder = new NodeBuilder()
    stepNodes << nodeBuilder.'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder' {
        jdk('(Inherit From Job)')
        usePrivateRepository(false)
        project('${your.path.here}')
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like that. Thanks.